# PHP get value from dynamically named $_POST variable

Tags: php, variables, post, dynamic

This is my code.  Unfortunately this causes a parse error.  Can anyone think of a better way to do this?

```
$data = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM TreatmentTypes ORDER BY TreatmentType ASC");
while($row = $data->fetch_assoc())
{
    $str = row['TreatmentTypeID'];
    echo "<br><br><br>".$_POST['txt'.$str];
}
```

Comment: You probably want to use variable variables. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: You have to set same name in html form for that value.

Comment: why $_POST[]; for variable on same page? directly echo $str;

Comment: You are missing `$` at the beginning of `row['TreatmentTypeID'];` -> `$str = row['TreatmentTypeID'];`

Answer (score 3):

Judging by your sample you are missing an $ in `row['TreatmentTypeID'];` so it should be `$row['TreatmentTypeID'];`